# Optical Mark Reader

Tags: java

Preciso ler um arquivo .pdf e gerar relatórios baseados nos dados obtidos desse arquivo.

Certa vez, fiz um sistema específico para uma gráfica, que interpretava as respostas dos candidatos de um concurso público. O sistema interpretava as marcações (das respostas) dos alunos e cruzava os dados com o gabarito da prova, gerando um relatório com base nesses dados, etc.

Enfim, acontece que "ler" um .pdf, que contém textos, números, etc.. é algo bem mais complexo.

Qual a melhor maneira de atacar esse tipo de problema? Alguém pode me auxiliar com algum material ou qualquer outra pista.

Comment: Uma das alternativas para ler um pdf ou uma imagem é usando o Opencv (uma biblioteca de computação visual que possui um Port para Java). Dependendo do que você vai fazer e como a informação está disposta no documento, pode ser necessário usar alguma ferramenta mais específica, como o Tesseract, por exemplo.

Comment: Na verdade, creio que o seu problema seja melhor descrito como extração de texto de um documento. Veja uma implementação usando o OpenCV para [extrair textos de cartões de visita](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506105/extracting-text-opencv). Seria melhor postar um modelo do documento em questão usando a Tag [tag:opencv] mostrando como as informações estão dispostas que a comunidade pode ajudar mais.